# $ Composer can't find mongodb extension, required Mongodb extension

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, composer-php, lumen-5.4

I'm using with latest php version 7.2 on macOS (Mojave / Big Sur / Monterey / Ventura / Sonoma) and receiving error like

```
 $composer require mongodb/mongodb
Using version ^1.4 for mongodb/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

> **For more information about question : see the screenshoot**

[image]

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.

> Problem 1
> - mongodb/mongodb v1.4.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> **- Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.4 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.x-dev, v1.4.x-dev].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

I have already installed mongoDB extension still receiving problem [image]

Not sure what I've missed steps to installation. If anyone can help me with this composer problem, I'd greatly appreciate it. in advance Thanks.

Comment: multiple php versions installed maybe? CLI different version than server?

Comment: Hey @Kalpesh-gamit, how did you installed the mongodb extension. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> composer require mongodb/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs
composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs

Using version ^3.4 for jenssegers/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing mongodb/mongodb (1.4.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing jenssegers/mongodb (v3.4.5): Downloading (100%)         
jenssegers/mongodb suggests installing jenssegers/mongodb-session (Add MongoDB session support to Laravel-MongoDB)
jenssegers/mongodb suggests installing jenssegers/mongodb-sentry (Add Sentry support to Laravel-MongoDB)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
```

[image]

`composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs`
**It solved my problem.**

Comment: Does this method need to add --ignore-platform-reqs for any other packages as composer resolves dependencies?

Answer (score 10):

Install PHP extension by running this command on your terminal.

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

At the end, you will see following information.

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.3/pecl/20180731/mongodb.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongodb-1.5.3
Extension mongodb enabled in php.ini
```

and then restart your PHP service.

Comment: when I run above command then received "sudo: pecl: command not found"

Comment: without sudo working commando but again received problem "pecl install mongodb"

Comment: In my case I was using docker and I did in Dockerfile.dev:
`RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb`

Answer (score 5):

Please check if mongodb modules is installed

> php -m

Go to the installation directory and run the below command ( it will take some time)

> composer require mongodb/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs

This will ignore the MongoDB required packages & rest will be installed.

If you want the MongoDB Module to be installed then execute the below command

> sudo apt-get install php-mongodb

Answer (score 3):

This error will happen when using WAMP as there is an unique php.ini for WAMP and CMD.

So you might have added the mongo-ext to your WAMP php.ini and so it looks as though it is running and included in the enabled extension's list. However, this is not available to the command line php.ini and also you need to confirm the CMD version of PHP you are running

- You can confirm your CMD PHP version in the windows ENV variable "path"
- If the CMD php version is not the same as the version you have included your
  mongo-ext, you will have to either install the mongo-ext into that version of PHP or change your path variable to point to the version of PHP you are  currently using
- Then ensure that the `extension=php_mongodb` is setup in both your WAMP and CMD version of php.ini

In order to confirm you have been successful your mongo-ext will show in your phpinfo() and if you run `php -m` on the CMD it will show in the rendered list

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs
```

The above is not the correct way to do it, as it will create problems into the future with other packages, updates and/or installs.

Answer (score -1):

For those who want to fix this issue on **Windows**, you need to download the correct DLL file and configure it properly in your PHP environment. Here's a step-by-step guide to help you resolve the problem:

1. **Check PHP Version:**
   First, determine your PHP version by running the following command in your Command Prompt or Terminal:

   ```
   php -v
   ```

   Take note of the PHP version, as you'll need this information in the next steps.
2. **Identify Architecture and Thread Safety:**
   Next, check if the Thread Safety (TS) is enabled or disabled. Run the following command:

   ```
   php -i | findstr "Thread Safety"
   ```

   If "Thread Safety" is **enabled**, you have a thread-safe (TS) version.
3. **Download the Correct DLL File:**
   Now, visit the project's » Github releases page ([https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/)) and look for the appropriate archive that matches your PHP version, architecture, and thread safety.

   For example, if you have PHP 8.2, x64 architecture, and TS enabled, the correct file would be named something like `php_mongodb-1.x.8.2-ts-x64.zip`. Make sure to choose the exact combination that matches your PHP environment.
4. **Copy DLL to PHP Extension Directory:**
   After downloading extract and copy the DLL file to your PHP extension directory. By default, the extension directory is named "ext" and is located within your PHP installation folder (e.g., `C:\php\ext` on Windows).
5. **Update php.ini:**
   Open your PHP configuration file (php.ini) and add the following line at the end:

   ```
   extension=php_mongodb
   ```

   Save the php.ini file after making the change.
6. **Restart Web Server:**
   Finally, restart your web server (e.g., Wamp) to apply the changes.