# Composer install mongo db version problem

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php

I want to install a package using composer for my PHP project.

I tried this first:

`composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs`

But it doesn't work with this method. Therefore, I removed the mongodb and after install again.

But it doesn't work this method.

```
composer install

Problem 1
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb 1.4.2 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.2].
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.5.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.2].
    - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb v3.5.0 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.5.0].
```

Comment: Did you try to install `ext-mongodb`, e.g. with command like `pecl install mongodb`? If that library requires it, you gotta supply it.

Comment: yes i tried this way.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Installing does not stop error for `pecl install mongodb` . But when I say `composer install` in PhpStorm, it gives the above error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you're trying to say. Maybe there will be others willing to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$ Composer can't find mongodb extension, required Mongodb extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566245/composer-cant-find-mongodb-extension-required-mongodb-extension)

Comment: Same question but my problem is not solved, it continues.